# Connect Elastic Load Balancer instance to back-end database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-elb

I have an application hosted on Amazon AWS with backend database. Web application is controlled by Elastic Load Balancer with Autoscaling. MySQL databse is on the other instance within the same zone. The problem is that connection could be established only if I add rule in MySQL security group to connect on 3306 from 0.0.0.0. or if I add individual IP address of each instance. However, if I assign "Autoscale security group" or "Load Balancer security group" it doesn't work. Isn't that supposed to work if I assign security group where instances belongs to the MySQL security group?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved the issue with the help of Amazon technical support for developers. It turned out that back-end instance is only accessible through the Amazon private IP address. I was always trying to access it through it's public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

AWS allows ingress between two security groups only if they are configured in the same region. For your spcific case, modify the security group settings for the Mysql server allowing in-bound 3306 port traffic from `AccountId/OtherSecurityGroup` e.g 111122223333/OtherSecurityGroup

Comment: It was not in the same region, and I set it now. However, it still doesn't work. I also tried to add accountId/autoscaleSecurityGroup, and once it's saved it resolve to autoscaleSecurityGroup, like I already had, but still nothing.